# Images not taking up 100% of div height

Tags: html, css

I am working on a test site with a fairly easy layout. It's divided up into rows of two columns with alternating widths. My problem is, for whatever reason, my image inserted into one of the column divs is not taking up 100% height of the div. It's short by a few pixels. This is a problem because the two columns in the same row need to appear to be "equal height."

I put a red background on one of the divs with the image problem so you can easily see what I am talking about. I am sure it's fairly simple and I am just overlooking something, but on this Monday morning I can't seem to find it. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my test site: http://hartsfielddesign.com/test2/test.html

Comment: when I pull it up in firebug, the layout doesn't show any padding on the img or the div

Comment: show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why an image inside a div has an extra space below the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sometimes inline images have extra padding on the bottom due to inline text sizes/line heights.

Set the div with image to

```
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ZC7Xa/1/

edit:

alternatively, set the `<img />` to `display:block;` so the inline padding isn't applied

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ZC7Xa/3/

Comment: That's exactly what i needed. Thanks man. Not sure I would have thought of the `display:block` on the img.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `vertical-align:top` to your images rule:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZC7Xa/2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! That blows my mind that this actually works, but it does it perfect. Why would this fix things?

Comment: It works because since images are inline elements, they sit vertically like text does which includes extra space for descenders (e.g. 'j', 'y', 'g', etc.). Specifying the vertical-align top hikes it up to remove that space.

Comment: Got it. Now it makes total sense. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This works like charm. I didn't know that images would behave like a normal text

Answer (score 1):

This code work 100% for me.

```
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
```

put it on Parent of img tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish, you could set a height value on the `<div class="product clearfix color-box">` elements, say `200px` for example, and then have the `.vendor` and `.vendor-images`, as well as the `img` contained within those, set to `height: 100%`

Comment: Thanks Kyle. That solution would definitely work, but I was hoping to come up with an answer that wouldn't force a set height on each row because they will all be different. Should have stated that in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong aspect ratio on your image. It is too long.

What you can do to make it easier is to give .vendor-images the image as a background instead of using an img tag. Then you can stretch it out so it doesn't give you that errror.

You could also make the left small image a float:left value and the right float:right and use like 30% width on the left and 65% width on the right. Set no padding and the remaing 5% will give you that padding.

or you could just simply change the aspect ratio of your image.

Comment: Even though my image is originally too long, shouldn't the div shrink to it's height since it is the only element within the div and img is set to `max-width="100%"`?

Also, can you give a div a background img without setting an explicit height?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class .box-expand, .color-box-expand margin and padding. Then set the height on each div. Then it will work properly.

Comment: Yes, that would totally work, but I was trying to accomplish this without having to set a height. Should have stated that.